# How to fetch Records for every month?

Tags: java, date, jdbc

I am using JDBC with Java to fetch account IDs records like below:

```
select s.account_id, s.status, o.phonenumber
from table1 s, table2 o
where s.valid_from='1-DEC-16'
  and o.phonenumber IS NOT NULL
  and s.validTo=sysdate 
  and s.status='active'
  and and s.account_id = o.account_id;
```

In result set I am getting all accountids for active records. Is there any way I can execute this query every month and output account IDs at the end of every month? In that case how should I give `valid_from` and `valid_to` dates automatically?

Comment: There are so many schedulers available online that would let you automate things, including the native cron in Linux. So yes there are many ways, please be more specific as to the requirements and environment and your project in particular. You could use `new Date()` to fetch the current date for `valid_to` and use the `Calendar.Add()` from the Calendar class to get date a month back for the `valid_from`. It would be really easy to help you if you provide some more code instead of just the query.

Comment: Rather than the long outdated `Date` and `Calendar`, just use `LocalDate` from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. [See the tutorial here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also @Exception_al

Comment: Noted @OleV.V. . But isn't LocalDate new in Java8+ ? Anyway, OPs question still stays way too broad to provide any help.

Comment: @Exception_al For Java 6 and Java 7, much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project.

Answer (score 0):

Use smart objects, not dumb strings, when you exchanging data with your database.

With JDBC 4.2 or later, you can directly exchange modern *java.time* objects with your database.

For a date-only value, use `LocalDate`. To get the first day of month, use `YearMonth`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( “Africa/Tunis” ) ;
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.now( z ) ;
LocalDate firstOfThisMonth = ym.atDay( 1 ) ;
LocalDate firstOfNextMonth = ym.plusMonths( 1 ).atDay( 1 ) ;
```

Use SQL something like:

```
… WHERE happened >= ? AND happened < ?
```

Pass a value for that placeholder.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , firstOfMonth ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 2 , firstOfNextMonth ) ;
```

This approach is known as **Half-Open**, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. Usually the best way to define a span of time. Note that for this approach we do *not* use the SQL operator `BETWEEN` as it is fully closed.

Retrieval.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```